# Установка программ из консоли в fedora

Tags: fedora

Раньше пользовал ubuntu и чтоб там поставить программу вводил

```
sudo apt-get install smth
```

Как сделать это в федоре 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum install "пакет"

Comment: Советую использовать dnf вместо yum

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно верно...Если необходимо установить несколько пакетов то пишем имена через пробел:
 yum install packet1 packet2 packetX
Желательно воспользоваться инструкцией к yum : [Работа с yum](http://wiki.russianfedora.ru/index.php/Работа_с_Yum) , в частности, а так же иными инструкциями проекта на их [wiki-сайте](http://wiki.russianfedora.ru/) + [Основная страница проекта RFRemix](http://russianfedora.ru) (основан на Fedora, так что много полезного найдете у них)

Comment: Советую использовать dnf вместо yum. Yum вроде как уже давно deprecated

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor Досточтимый сэр, Вы бы на даты посмотрели... Это было более 8 лет назад